# Make user click elements in certain order

Tags: jquery, click

I have this basic layout of a grid of 20 numbers, (1-20). I want the user to click the elements in numerical order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...), and the `highlight` class will move from each number, **if** it's the correct order, ex: the number `1` is red, if the user clicks `2`, `2` will now be red, but if the user clicks `3` after clicking `1` (wrong order), then nothing happens. I've gotten the grid laid out, given each `div` the id the same as it's value, and I've given each element a `data-value` attribute... I'm just not sure how to make the user click in order and then move the `highlight` class...

Here's my fiddle that I've been working with: [Number grid with click order](http://jsfiddle.net/tdunham02/EB654/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EB654/30/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 2; //start at 2 if you don't want the user to click on 1

    for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        $('#numbers').append('<div id="' + i + '" class="num ' + ((i == 1) ? 'highlight' : '') + '" data-value="' + i + '">' + i + '</div>');
    }

    $(".num").height($(document).height() / 5);
    $(".num").width($(document).width() / 4);

    $('.num').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).data('value') == counter) {
            $('.num').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
            counter++;
        }

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Above probably works, but may I suggest making the `counter` not global?

Comment: True. I wrote it pretty fast. I will post an optimized version in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 answers correct! Thanks for this answer @ComputerArts!!

Comment: Accept @ComputerArts' once he has removed that nasty global in it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should get you started:

```
(function($) {
    var currentNumber = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '.num', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.data('value') != currentNumber + 1) {
            return;
        }

        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        currentNumber++;
        $this.addClass('highlight');

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EB654/9/

Comment: This works great! Is there an advantage to using a function rather than ComputerArts method of `.click()`?

Comment: When using `.on()` you will be more flexible because it will keep working when you dynamically add more numbers later. Not a big one though if the number will be static. I just like my code to be future proof.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.num').click(function() {
    var currentEle = $(this);
    var val = parseInt(currentEle.attr("data-value"),10);
    var prevEle = $(".num.highlight").first();
    var prev_val = parseInt(prevEle.attr("data-value"),10);
    if(++prev_val==val){
         prevEle.removeClass("highlight");
         currentEle.addClass("highlight");
    }
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/EB654/15/ .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that should work
http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/EB654/28

Replace your click function with this:

```
var i = 2;

$(".num").click(function(){
    clicked_val = $(this).attr("data-value")

    if (clicked_val != i){
          return 
    }

  $(this).addClass('highlight');
  i = i+1

})
```